# Looking for good trackpad and trackpoint software or values for Thinkpad T14S

Tags: touchpad, trackpoint

I own a Thinkpad T14S running ubuntu 20.04.

I tried tweaking around, but the trackpoint (red little joystick in middle of keyboard) and trackpad never feel as good as in windows 11.

Anybody have some recommendation of software or specific acceleration value to improve this ?